# Getting action not found error in play framework when file downloading?

Tags: javascript, playframework

I am very new to working with file concepts in java and i have a files in my folder and when i click on the file link in my page it shows action not found error page.How to solve it?Do i need to set any configurations in play?Please help me and for all help thanks in advance.

```
This is my link:
<td><a href="/INVOICEPROCESSINGSYSTEM/@hoForm.filePath" class="fancyboxPDF" title="@hoForm.fileName" onclick="OpenFancyBoxForHeadOfficeFormsView('@hoForm.id');">@hoForm.fileName</a></td>
```

And my js code is:
    function OpenFancyBoxForHeadOfficeFormsView(hoFormId){

```
    $(".fancyboxPDF").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        width:1200,
        height:1000,
        autoSize: true,
        type: 'iframe',
        loop : false,
        helpers : { 

          overlay : {closeClick: false}, // disables close when outside clcik 
        },
        iframe: {
            preload: false // fixes issue with iframe and IE
        }
    }); 
}
```

Files are showing correctly without any error in production server.But in my local system getting error page with action not found. 
[image]

Comment: Please respond anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got answer after doing some changes.in play it shows action not found error page.what i did is i generate war file and run it in tomcat.it works perfectly.I think i missed some path to give in play and that is the reason it shows error while run in polay framework.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to route the URL to your function.

You must have in `conf/routes` file:

```
GET /INVOICEPROCESSINGSYSTEM/     YourControllerClass.OpenFancyBoxForHeadOfficeFormsView(hoFormId: String)
```

Documentation: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaRouting

Comment: i don't have this  OpenFancyBoxForHeadOfficeFormsView() in my controller it is in js code.Do i need to route this method?how can you please explain.

Comment: play must have some functions to serve the `/INVOICEPROCESSINGSYSTEM/` URL. You wrote it works on prod, maybe there is another system on prod that serves this path.  

Typically the static files are routed by default `Assets` controller like this

`GET         /assets/*file                     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`

Comment: yes,you are right still i confused how to route this js method in routes file.please help me.

Comment: it's have nothing to js method, I supposed that 'OpenFancyBoxForHeadOfficeFormsView' is a Java method that serving the `/INVOICEPROCESSINGSYSTEM/*` UTL. My suggestion is not correct.

And you wrote that it works on prod, so I think that some other system serves `/INVOICEPROCESSINGSYSTEM/*` URL and you just have no this system on local.